# Opacity of div container affecting child

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a background and opacity set. In it, I have a child. I want the child to appear to be on top of the container, but it isn't, the opacity affects the child.

[image]

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="child">some label</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: lightblue;
    z-index: 10;
```

}

```
.child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

For other reasons, the container must have a position of absolute.

The jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jv0tt5rz/1/).

How can I avoid the opacity of the container affecting the child?

Comment: @NenadVracar You mean `rgba(207,230,237,.5)`

Comment: Set the `background` and `opacity` on a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L60mqe5a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    //opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: rgba(173,216,230,0.5);
    z-index: 10;
}
```